# Is every rational realized as the Euler characteristic of some manifold or orbifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, orbifolds

Let me first ask the question for two-dimensional compact, connected manifolds and orbifolds.
Then, if the answer is *No*, one can remove various conditions on the dimension,
and allow non-compact examples and disconnected examples, to realize a (perhaps) wider range of rationals.

This came up after a class I'm teaching and I didn't know the answer.

Related:

- MO question "[Euler characteristic of orbifolds](https://mathoverflow.net/q/51993/6094)."
- [Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold#2-dimensional_orbifolds) for 2-dim orbifolds

Comment: Well, allowing *non connected* examples it seems to me that the answer is *yes*. In fact, for any $n$ there is an orbifold whose Euler characteristic is $1/n$, and it is well known that any rational number can be written as a finite sum of fractions of this form (egyptian fraction representation).

Comment: You don't even need Egyptian fractions, just $m/n=m*1/n$. Of course, for the case of negative Euler characteristic, you should start with an orbifold with Euler characteristic $-1/n$.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Products of 2-orbifolds with manifolds will do the trick. There are 2-orbifolds of Euler characteristic $1/n$ (take a quotient of $S^2$ by a rotation of order $2n$). Then take a product with a manifold of Euler characteristic $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ to get all rationals.

Answer (score 27):

The answer for connected 2-dimensional orbifolds is no. Euler characteristic is
$$\chi(O)=\chi(M)-\sum\left(1-\frac{1}{q}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right),$$
where $p,q\geq 2$ are integers, and $\chi(M)$ is the characteristic of the surface
of the orbifold. It immediately follows that $\chi(O)\leq 2$ for all 2D orbiforlds, and as $1-1/q\geq 1/2$, $1-1/p\geq 1/2$, most rational numbers will never occur (on any closed interval which does not contain half-integers, there are only
finitely many of these numbers).

Comment: In fact, these numbers are well-ordered.

Comment: @Ian Agol: Yes. Interesting whether this ordering of orbifolds has any meaning.