# Euler characteristic of *hyperbolic* orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

This is a follow-up to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267055/is-every-rational-realized-as-the-euler-characteristic-of-some-manifold-or-orbif) Which rational numbers arise as Euler characteristics of orbifold quotients of $\mathbb{H}^n?$ The answer is not even clear for $n=2.$ It is clear that the Euler characteristic is negative, and is not bigger than that of the $2, 3, 7$ triangle orbifold (so, no smaller than $1/84$ in absolute value), but what the range is otherwise is not quite clear. In higher dimensions, an analogous result is [shown by Adeboye and Wei](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~wei/paper/Adeboye-Wei.pdf), so for each *fixed* (even) dimension there is a lower bound on the absolute value of the Euler characteristic, but once the dimension is unrestricted, things are less clear.

Comment: In the arithmetic case, the smallest orbifold has Euler characteristic of the order of $10^{-15}$ and dimension 16, see http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_2004_5_3_4_749_0.pdf

Comment: For hyperbolic 2-orbifolds, this is connected to open questions in number theory. The euler characteristic of a triangle orbifold is -1+1/p+1/q+/1r. Then one can realize a rational $-1+4/n (n>4)$ iff the Erdös-Strauss conjecture holds. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Straus_conjecture